# What are the main differences between Kohana 3.2 and Kohana 3.3

Tags: kohana, kohana-3.2, kohana-3.3

On my first view I haven't found no principled differences except new `vendor` folder.

What are they?

Comment: Maybe this upgrade guide for implementing PSR-0 helps.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935621/a-guide-to-upgrade-from-kohana-3-2-to-3-3-implementing-psr-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at documentation:
http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/upgrading

Answer (score 1):

- New module - [Minion](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/minion).
- A [little change](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/orm/upgrading) in
  ORM module.

Comment: The ORM change was made before, not this time.