# How to upgrade from Kohana 3.2 to 3.3 (implementing PSR-0)?

Tags: unix, kohana, command-line-interface, kohana-3.2, kohana-3.3

What steps do I need tot take to upgrade from Kohana 3.2 to 3.3 with respect to the implementation of PSR-0 and what commands have to be executed from the command line?

Comment: Please reformat this into a question and answer pair if you want it to stay on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Unix command line:**

These are the steps I took to implement PSR-0 in my Kohana application.

I removed the following system/ dir:

```
rm -rf system
```

In your current bootstrap.php the only change is to make the classes start with an upper, so best is to keep your old bootstrap and just change the following lines on top of the file:

```
// Load the core Kohana class
require SYSPATH.'classes/Kohana/Core'.EXT;

if (is_file(APPPATH.'classes/Kohana'.EXT))
{
  // Application extends the core
  require APPPATH.'classes/Kohana'.EXT;
}
else
{
  // Load empty core extension
  require SYSPATH.'classes/Kohana'.EXT;
}
```

Remove the bootstrap.php from the new kohana release dir. Now copy paste all files of 3.3 to your old application:

```
cp -R path/to/new/kohana/* .
```

Now move all your controllers and models to the capitalised dirs and remove the old dirs:

```
mv application/classes/controller/* application/classes/Controller
mv application/classes/model/* application/classes/Model
rm -rf application/classes/controller application/classes/model
```

The vendor dir has a fixed place in the root of the kohana dir. Move your vendor dir from application/vendor (if you have one there) to vendor/

```
mv application/vendor .
```

Edit the database config file (e.g. application/config/database.php), all "type" properties should be capitalised:

```
  return array
  (
    'default' => array
    (
      'type'       => 'MySQL',
```

When you use the AUTH orm driver and you have overwritten the config in application/config/auth.php, uppercase the driver name:

```
return array(
  'driver'       => 'ORM',
```

Now comes the tricky part, all class names and file names of these classes should be capitalised. Go to the classes dir.

```
cd application/classes
```

And copy paste this command:

```
  for SRC in `find . -depth`
  do DST=`dirname "${SRC}"`/`basename "${SRC}" | sed -e 's/^./\U&/'`;
      if [ "${SRC}" != "${DST}" ]
      then
        [ ! -e "${DST}" ] && mv -T "${SRC}" "${DST}" || echo "${SRC} was not renamed"
      fi
  done
```

(source: http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/comment/73089#Comment_73089)

This command recursively checks all dirs and capitalizes the filenames. Go to the application dir.

```
cd ../
```

Now inside the models and controllers (and helpers), capitalise all class names. So Controller_template_parent must become Controller_Template_Parent. I have some very inefficient commands for this one (so please contribute).

```
find ./ -name \*.php -exec sed  -i "s/helper_\([a-zA-Z]\+\)/Helper_\u\1/gI" {} \;
find ./ -name \*.php -exec sed  -i "s/helper_\([a-zA-Z]\+\)_\([a-zA-Z]\+\)/Helper_\u\1_\u\2/gI" {} \;
find ./ -name \*.php -exec sed  -i "s/helper_\([a-zA-Z]\+\)_\([a-zA-Z]\+\)_\([a-zA-Z]\+\)/Helper_\u\1_\u\2_\u\3/gI" {} \;
```

The ./ in the beginning is for all files (recursive dirs), that end in .php. I added a "I" behind the sed command to make the search case insensitive.
(source command: https://askubuntu.com/questions/84007/find-and-replace-text-within-multiple-files)

The first command will replace helper_some_thing_here with Helper_Some_thing_here. The second command will convert helper_some_thing_here to Helper_Some_Thing_here etc. So if you have class names with more than 3 underscores in it, you can build your own command.

The same needs to be done for classes starting with Model_ and Controller_

```
find ./ -name \*.php -exec sed  -i "s/model_\([a-zA-Z]\+\)/Model_\u\1/gI" {} \;
find ./ -name \*.php -exec sed  -i "s/model_\([a-zA-Z]\+\)_\([a-zA-Z]\+\)/Model_\u\1_\u\2/gI" {} \;
find ./ -name \*.php -exec sed  -i "s/model_\([a-zA-Z]\+\)_\([a-zA-Z]\+\)_\([a-zA-Z]\+\)/Model_\u\1_\u\2_\u\3/gI" {} \;

find ./ -name \*.php -exec sed  -i "s/controller_\([a-zA-Z]\+\)/Controller_\u\1/gI" {} \;
find ./ -name \*.php -exec sed  -i "s/controller_\([a-zA-Z]\+\)_\([a-zA-Z]\+\)/Controller_\u\1_\u\2/gI" {} \;
find ./ -name \*.php -exec sed  -i "s/controller_\([a-zA-Z]\+\)_\([a-zA-Z]\+\)_\([a-zA-Z]\+\)/Controller_\u\1_\u\2_\u\3/gI" {} \;
```

Now some class names that were used with only 1 capital, are now written in full capitals (Html, Url, Http, UTF8). Replace them in your whole application.

Execute this command in the application/ dir:

```
find ./ -name \*.php -exec sed -i "s/Url::/URL::/gI" {} \;
find ./ -name \*.php -exec sed -i "s/Html::/HTML::/gI" {} \;
find ./ -name \*.php -exec sed -i "s/Http::/HTTP::/gI" {} \;
find ./ -name \*.php -exec sed -i "s/Utf8::/UTF8::/gI" {} \;
```

When you use the ORM driver, all your Orm::factory('some_class') should be upper cased and capitalised to ORM::factory('Some_Class'). I use the same command to uppercase all ORM classes and to capitalise the class names in the factory.

```
find ./ -name \*.php -exec sed -i  "s/orm::factory(\(\"\|'\)\([a-zA-Z_]\+\)\(\"\|'\)\(,[^,]*\)*)/ORM::factory('\u\2'\4)/gI" {} \;
find ./ -name \*.php -exec sed -i  "s/orm::factory(\(\"\|'\)\([a-zA-Z]\+\)_\([a-zA-Z]\+\)\(\"\|'\)\(,[^,]*\)*)/ORM::factory('\u\2_\u\3'\5)/gI" {} \;
find ./ -name \*.php -exec sed -i  "s/orm::factory(\(\"\|'\)\([a-zA-Z]\+\)_\([a-zA-Z]\+\)_\([a-zA-Z]\+\)\(\"\|'\)\(,[^,]*\)*)/ORM::factory('\u\2_\u\3_\u\4'\6)/gI" {} \;
```

Now my modules where not compatible anymore since 3.3, not all of them are upgraded. When you want to upgrade them yourself, you probably have to check them separately go to the classes dir of every module, capitalise it's file and it's class names. You can use previous commands.

For me this is a checklist when upgrading an application, like I said, please feel free to contribute so upgrading is made easier.

Comment: Something's wrong with your updated pattern. It transformed ORM::factory('user', ['is_deleted' => 0]); into ORM::factory('User', 'is_deleted' => 0]); (it removed the opening square bracket). In newer versions of php [] is the short notation for array() and ORM::factory('bla', array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2)) is an acceptable way of selecting something with ORM (instead of where()->where()). I think you should match just ORM::factory('bla' and replace that bit with ORM::factory('Bla' regardless of what's next. Also, it seems to me that you use just single quotes, no double? 'bla', not "bla" ?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I don't get the same result when I fire the first ORM update pattern on my command line like this: echo "ORM::factory('user', ['is_deleted' => 0]);" | sed -e  "s/orm::factory('\([a-zA-Z_]\+\)'\(,[^,]*\)*)/ORM::factory('\u\1'\2)/gI". The result is: ORM::factory('User', ['is_deleted' => 0]);. I updated the pattern for double quotes.

Comment: Indeed, I found out meanwhile that it stripped more. Try with ORM::factory('user', ['abc' => 1, 'def' => 2]);

Answer (score 3):

Based on Daan's answer and more i wrote a php script to upgrade Kohana v3.2 to v3.3

It's available on github :
https://github.com/Choufourax/upgrade-kohana-3_2-to-3_3

Or below :

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
/*

A PHP SCRIPT TO UPGRADE FROM KOHANA 3.2.X TO KOHANA 3.3.X
------------------------------------------------------

Based on the works of :  
=> Daan (http://stackoverflow.com/users/987864/daan)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935621/how-to-upgrade-from-kohana-3-2-to-3-3-implementing-psr-0  
=> Alex Cartwright <alexc223@gmail.com>
https://github.com/AlexC/kohana-upgrade-script

This script is designed to do bulk changes to your codebase that can
easily be automated, changes that would otherwise have the potential
to take a very long time for a large project. It does not provide a
fully automated migration, and it is highly recommended that you read
the official Kohana 3.3 upgrade guide before running this script.
http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/upgrading

------------------------------------------------------

Be smart, be safe :
BACKUP YOUR WEBSITE BEFORE RUNNING THIS SCRIPT
------------------------------------------------------

This script handles :
- Changes in Bootstrap / database config file / auth config file
- PSR-0 support (file/class naming conventions)
    - Change the file names 
    - Change the name of class in all files  (including calls, extends...)
- Case sensitive ORM, HTTP, URL, UTF8, HTML classes
- New syntax for Browser cache checking
- New syntax for Redirects (HTTP 300, 301, 302, 303, 307)
- Apply the changes listed above in Modules too
- Moving the vendor folder

This script does not handle :
- HTTP Exceptions
- Custom Error Pages (HTTP 500, 404, 403, 401 etc)
- Query Builder Identifier Escaping
- Route Filters

Things to do :
- improve regex to prevent replacement mistakes between class and functions

HOW TO USE
------------------------------------------------------

This script is to use on your local version of your website
Do not use on your production server (as you will experiment permission issues as your server is not supose to let you modify PHP files dynamically for security reasons)
Once your local site is updated and you test everything, upload files via FTP to your production server. 

1/ Backup your site

2/ Download kohana 3.3

3/ Manulay replace the following folders from Kohana 3.3 to the website to upgrade :
- system
- modules/auth
- modules/cache
- modules/codebench
- modules/database
- modules/image
- modules/minion
- modules/orm
- modules/unittest
- modules/userguide

4/ Edit the settings at the begining of the script 

5/ Run this file
   - if you use a Mac : the best way will be to open the php file with BBedit and chose in the '#!' menu "Run in Terminal"  
   - you can also open a Terminal, go to the script folder and type ./upgrade-kohana.php  
   - you can also just run the script from your local webserver http://localhost/website/upgrade-kohana.php but it's not recommended as you may have some permissions problem to modify the PHP files  

------------------------------------------------------

AUTHOR
------------------------------------------------------

@author Erwan Dupeux-Maire  
www.upyupy.fr  
www.bwat.fr  

*/


/*
---------------
SETTINGS
---------------
*/
// START OF SETTINGS
// Path to kohana v3.2 website to update 
$path = '/Library/WebServer/Documents/work/bwat/bwat/';

// List of folders to process (at least $path.'application' )
// You sould not use this script to upgrade third party modules that already have a v3.3 version.
$dirs = array (
    $path.'application',
    $path.'modules/a1',
    $path.'modules/a2',
    $path.'modules/acl',
    $path.'modules/admin',
    $path.'modules/adminfiles',
    $path.'modules/adminnl',
    /*
    $path.'modules/auth',
    $path.'modules/cache',
    $path.'modules/codebench',
    $path.'modules/database',
    $path.'modules/image',
    $path.'modules/minion',
    $path.'modules/orm',
    $path.'modules/unittest',
    $path.'modules/userguide'
    */
);

// Search and replace class name in "views" folders to update the case ?
// true => yes | false => no
$checkInViews = true;

// If there is some files you don't want to process, add them to this array
$skip = array('_notes','.DS_Store','lib-mail-phpmailer','lib-rtf');

// Special class rewrinting 
// sometimes, captialize is not enought
// Use this array to set special changes()
$specials = array (
    'upyupy' =>'UpyUpy',
    'gd' => 'GD',
    'orm' => 'ORM',
    'db' => 'DB',
    'mysql' => 'MySQL',
    'pdo' => 'PDO',
    'html' => 'HTML',
    'url' => 'URL',
    'http' => 'HTTP',
    'utf8' => 'UTF8',
    'validurl' => 'ValidURL',
    'validcolor' => 'ValidColor',
    'userfuncarray' => 'UserFuncArray',
    'urlsite' => 'URLSite',
    'stripnullbytes' => 'StripNullBytes',
    'mddoincludeviews' => 'MDDoIncludeViews',
    'mddoimageurl' => 'MDDoImageURL',
    'mddobaseurl' => 'MDDoBaseURL',
    'ltrimdigits' => 'LtrimDigits',
    'gruberurl' => 'GruberURL',
    'explodelimit' => 'ExplodeLimit',
    'datespan' => 'DateSpan',
    'autolinkemails' => 'AutoLinkEmails',
    'arrcallback' => 'ArrCallback'
);


// END OF SETTINGS


// Function to remove folders and files 
// @author : http://stackoverflow.com/users/1226894/baba
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835492/move-all-files-and-folders-in-a-folder-to-another
function rrmdir($dir) {
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        $files = scandir($dir);
        foreach ($files as $file)
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") rrmdir("$dir/$file");
        rmdir($dir);
    }
    else if (file_exists($dir)) unlink($dir);
}
// Function to Copy folders and files       
// @author : http://stackoverflow.com/users/1226894/baba
function rcopy($src, $dst) {
    if (file_exists ( $dst ))
        rrmdir ( $dst );
    if (is_dir ( $src )) {
        mkdir ( $dst );
        $files = scandir ( $src );
        foreach ( $files as $file )
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
                rcopy ( "$src/$file", "$dst/$file" );
    } else if (file_exists ( $src ))
        copy ( $src, $dst );
}

// Function to search and replace in a file (not case sensitive)
// @author : Erwan Dupeux-Maire
function replaceInFile($file, $search, $replace)
{
    if (!is_file($file))
    {
        echo $file.' does not exist (replaceInFile)'."<br />\n";
        return false;
    }
    $str = str_ireplace($search, $replace, file_get_contents($file));
    return file_put_contents($file, $str);
}
// Function to search and replace in a file with regex
// @author : Erwan Dupeux-Maire
function pregReplaceInFile($file, $search, $replace)
{
    if (!is_file($file))
    {
        echo $file.' does not exist (pregReplaceInFile)'."<br />\n";
        return false;
    }
    $str = preg_replace($search, $replace, file_get_contents($file));
    return file_put_contents($file, $str);
}


function rewritteFolderFiles($dir, $shortdir)
{
    global $path, $skip, $specials;
    //echo $dir."<br />\n";

    if (!is_dir($dir))
    {
        echo $dir.' does not exist (rewritteFolderFiles)'."<br />\n";
        return array();
    }


    // let's start the fun
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    $arr = array();
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..' && !in_array($ff, $skip))
        {
            //echo $dir.'/'.$ff."<br />\n";
            // Write classname
            $filename = str_replace(
                '.php', 
                '', 
                trim($shortdir.'/'.$ff, '/')
            );

            $arrPath = explode('/', $filename);
            foreach($arrPath as $k => $v)
            {
                if (isset($specials[strtolower($v)]))
                {
                    // in case u have some custom rewriting to do
                    $arrPath[$k] = $specials[strtolower($v)];
                }
                else
                {
                    // just capitalize
                    $arrPath[$k] = ucfirst($v);
                }
            }
            $classname = join('_',$arrPath);
            //echo $classname."<br />\n";


            if (is_file($dir.'/'.$ff) && strpos($ff, '.php')!==false)
            {
                // this array will be use to find/replace all occurences of a class name
                // Explanation and limits of this regex : see #NOTE1 at the end of this file.
                $arr['/(\(|\s|\t)('.$classname.')(\s)*(\(|\:\:|extends)/i'] = '$1'.$classname.'$3$4';

                $key = str_replace('.php', '', $ff);
                if (isset($specials[strtolower($key)]))
                {
                    // in case u have some custom rewriting to do
                    $nn = $specials[strtolower($key)].'.php';
                }
                else
                {
                    // just capitalize
                    $nn = ucfirst($ff);
                }
                // rename file
                rename($dir.'/'.$ff, $dir.'/'.$nn);
            }
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) 
            {
                if (isset($specials[strtolower($ff)]))
                {
                    // in case u have some custom rewriting to do
                    $nn = $specials[strtolower($ff)];
                }
                else
                {
                    // just capitalize
                    $nn = ucfirst($ff);
                }            
                // rename folder
                rename($dir.'/'.$ff, $dir.'/'.$nn);

                // merge without matching keys
                $arr = array_merge($arr, rewritteFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff, trim($shortdir.'/'.$ff, '/')));
            }
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}

function replaceClassNameInFolder($dir, $arrSearch, $arrReplace)
{
    global $skip;
    //echo $dir."<br />\n";

    if (!is_dir($dir))
    {
        echo $dir.' does not exist (replaceClassNameInFolder)'."<br />\n";
        return array();
    }

    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    $arr = array();
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..' && !in_array($ff, $skip))
        {
            if (is_file($dir.'/'.$ff) && strpos($ff, '.php')!==false)
            {
                $arr[] = $ff;
                pregReplaceInFile(
                    $dir.'/'.$ff,
                    $arrSearch,
                    $arrReplace
                );
            }
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) 
            {
                $arr[$ff] = replaceClassNameInFolder($dir.'/'.$ff, $arrSearch, $arrReplace);
            }
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}

$listOfRegexReplace = array();
foreach ($dirs as $dir)
{
    echo 'Processing '.$dir."......<br />\n";
    if ($dir == $path.'application')
    {
        // #1 manage bootstrap  
        // replace classes/kohana and classes/kohana/core
        // by classes/Kohana and classes/Kohana/Core
        replaceInFile(
            $dir.'/bootstrap.php', 
            array(
                'classes/kohana/core',
                'classes/kohana'
            ), 
            array(
                'classes/Kohana/Core',
                'classes/Kohana'
            )
        );

        // #2 move vendors
        if (file_exists($dir.'/vendor'))
        {
            rcopy($dir.'/vendor', $dir.'/../vendor' );
        }

        // #2bis add ignore_on_delete value in cache config if exists
        // (I experiment errors if ignore_on_delete is not an array in Kohana 3.3.0)
        if (file_exists($dir.'/config/cache.php'))
        {
            pregReplaceInFile(
                $dir.'/config/cache.php', 
                array(
                    '/((\'driver\')(\s)*(\=>)(\s)*(\'file\'))/i',
                ), 
                array(
                    '$1,
             \'ignore_on_delete\'   => array(
                    \'.gitignore\',
                    \'.git\',
                    \'.svn\'
             )'
                )
            );
        }
    }

    // #3 Edit the database config file, all "type" properties should be capitalised
    // should be only in application/config/database.php but may also be in modules/mymodule/config/database.php
    if (file_exists($dir.'/config/database.php'))
    {
        replaceInFile(
            $dir.'/config/database.php', 
            array(
                '\'mysql\'',
                '"mysql"',
                '"pdo"',
                '"pdo"'
            ), 
            array(
                '\'MySQL\'',
                '"MySQL"',
                '\'PDO\'',
                '"PDO"'
            )
        );      
    }

    // #4 Edit the auth config file if Auth module is used, driver name should be capitalised
    // should be only in application/config/auth.php but may also be in modules/mymodule/config/auth.php
    if (file_exists($dir.'/config/auth.php'))
    {
        replaceInFile(
            $dir.'/config/auth.php', 
            array(
                '\'orm\'',
                '"orm"',
                '\'file\'',
                '"file"'
            ), 
            array(
                '\'ORM\'',
                '"ORM"',
                '\'File\'',
                '"File"'
            )
        );      
    }

    // #5 in /classes and its subdirectories
    // rename all php files to match the case sensitive standard PSR-0
    $dir .= '/classes';
    if (!is_dir($dir))
    {
        echo $dir.' does not exist'."<br />\n";
        continue;
    }
    // Recursive function to update file and folder files and get back the list of class name to change
    $listOfRegexReplace = array_merge(
        $listOfRegexReplace,
        rewritteFolderFiles($dir, $shortdir='')
    );


}


// #10 some class names that were used with only 1 capital, are now written in full capitals (Html, Url, Http, UTF8). 
// Add them to the list of class to rewrite
$listOfRegexReplace['/(Html)(\:\:)/i'] = 'HTML$2';
$listOfRegexReplace['/(Url)(\:\:)/i'] = 'URL$2';
$listOfRegexReplace['/(Http)(\:\:)/i'] = 'HTTP$2';
$listOfRegexReplace['/(Utf8)(\:\:)/i'] = 'UTF8$2';

// #11 Replace orm::factory by ORM:factory etc....
$listOfRegexReplace['/(Orm)(\:\:)/i'] = 'ORM$2';

// #12 Update Redirects (HTTP 300, 301, 302, 303, 307)
// ->request->redirect becomes ->redirect
// Request::current()->redirect becomes HTTP::redirect
// Request::initial()->redirect becomes HTTP::redirect
$listOfRegexReplace['/(\->request)(\s)*(\->redirect)(\s)*/i'] = '->redirect';
$listOfRegexReplace['/(Request\:\:current\(\))(\s)*(\->redirect)/i'] = 'HTTP::redirect';
$listOfRegexReplace['/(Request\:\:initial\(\))(\s)*(\->redirect)/i'] = 'HTTP::redirect';

// #13 Browser cache checking (ETags)
// $this->response->check_cache becomes $this->check_cache
$listOfRegexReplace['/(\->response)(\s)*(\->check_cache)(\s)*/i'] = '->check_cache';

// If we want to harmonize the "OR" case
// $listOfRegexReplace['/ or die/i'] = ' OR die';


echo '---DISPLAY ALL REPLACEMENT REGEX ---'."<br />\n";
print_r($listOfRegexReplace);
echo '------'."<br />\n";

// #14 change all class names in php filesName in /classes
echo '---PROCESSING CLASSES---'."<br />\n";
echo '> Processing change class names '.$dir."<br />\n";
foreach ($dirs as $dir)
{
    $dir .= '/classes';
    echo 'Processing '.$dir."......<br />\n";
    echo 'This step can be long.'."<br />\n";
    replaceClassNameInFolder(
        $dir,
        array_keys($listOfRegexReplace),// arrSearch
        $listOfRegexReplace // arrSearch
    );
}

if ($checkInViews)
{

    // #15 change all class names in views files
    echo '---PROCESSING VIEWS---'."<br />\n";
    foreach ($dirs as $dir)
    {
        $dir .= '/views';
        echo 'Processing '.$dir."......<br />\n";
        echo 'This step can be long.'."<br />\n";
        replaceClassNameInFolder(
            $dir,
            array_keys($listOfRegexReplace),// arrSearch
            $listOfRegexReplace // arrSearch
        );
    }
}

/*
// #NOTE1 
// Explaination of the regex /(\(|\s|\t)(a1)(\s)*(\(|\:\:|extends)/i
// Find classname in a file : 
// - check something that start with space, tab or "("
// - followed by the name of the class (here "a1")
// - followed by one, several or no space
// - followed by "(" or ':' or "extends")
// - not cas sensitive
//
// The limit for now : can not distinct class declaration vs function declaration
// In ne following example, function a1()... should not be replace..
// 
$example = ' class a1 extends a1 () {
    function a1() {

    } 
    $title=\'a1\';
    $comment = "You shoudl take the highway a1! a1 is the fastest.";
    a1::doIt();
    $b = new a1();
    $c = Helper_Example(a1::action());
// with no indent ?
a1();
    // aaaa1bbbb
    // a1bbbb
    // aaa1
}';
$example = preg_replace(
    array('/(\(|\s|\t)(a1)(\s)*(\(|\:\:|extends)/i'), 
    array('$1A1$3$4'),
    $example
);
echo '<pre>'.($example).'</pre>';
// -----------------
// Result will be :
// -----------------
// class A1 extends A1 () {
//  function A1() {
//  
//  } 
//  $title='a1';
//  $comment = "You shoudl take the highway a1! a1 is the fastest.";
//  A1::doIt();
//  $b = new A1();
//  $c = Helper_Example(A1::action());
// // with no indent ?
// A1();
//  // aaaa1bbbb
//  // a1bbbb
//  // aaa1
// }
*/
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Great script. Has changed all my files, etc. I'm just curious as to what changes need applied to route filters? I'm having the problem where none of my routes are being found and I'm getting ```The requested URL / was not found on this server```.