# Kohana: server can't find core.php because of naming convention change

Tags: php, hosting, kohana, kohana-3

I have a project written in Kohana 3. The /system subdirectory is pulled in via a git submodule:

```
[submodule "system"]
    path = system
    url = git://github.com/kohana/core.git
```

After version 3.3 it seems all classes were changed to the first letter being upper-cased. ie core.php is now Core.php. This didn't seem to have any effect locally on my mac but now that I've uploaded my app to hosting provider Fort Rabbit I'm getting an error that it failed to open system/classes/kohana/core.php. I suspect this is because that is now system/classes/kohana/Core.php

Can anyone advise the best way to proceed? Do I need to change every instance of `require SYSPATH.'classes/kohana/classname'.EXT;` to the uppercase equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically yes. In 3.3 when you call a class, you have to be case sensitive. The same applies to the file names. [Migration guide](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/upgrading#psr-0-support-fileclass-naming-conventions) explains this quite well.
You can also check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935621/how-to-upgrade-from-kohana-3-2-to-3-3-implementing-psr-0) to automate the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'm confused as to how I'm only having these issues when uploading the project to the hosting server?

Comment: I'd shoot that the hosting is on Linux, which is case sensitive in opposite to Mac OS?